# Split a string based on delimeter

Tags: c++, boost

My delimeter could be anything except [0-9] ,[A-Z] case insensitive
I therefore would like a way to split my string based on the dynamic delimiter. 
I am currently using boost but am open to other solutions too.

The code I am currently using involves boost and is this:

```
vector<string> split_;
boost::split(split,line,boost::is_any_of("\t"));
```

How can I adjust the above code so it could conform to my delimiter standards ? 
Is there any other library that could help me accomplish this ?
Any suggestions ?

Comment: Construct an `std::string` containing your continuously changing delimiters and pass that to `is_any_of`?

Comment: If they can change during the string parsing, you might consider just using a plain state machine to process your input character-by-character.

Comment: No they wont change. I just know it could be anything but [0-9] or [A-z] or [a-z]

Comment: Just updated the post for further clarificattion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Predicates can be combined:

```
        !(
            boost::is_from_range('a','z') || 
            boost::is_from_range('A','Z') || 
            boost::is_from_range('0','9')
         )
```

This magic is due to Boost Lambda library AFAIR. Anyways, you can use it:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/96a3377b900236e2)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> split_;
    std::string line("one;two#three//four five\r\n"
            "six");
    boost::split(split_,line,
            !(
                boost::is_from_range('a','z') || 
                boost::is_from_range('A','Z') || 
                boost::is_from_range('0','9')
             )
            );

    for(auto const& s : split_)
        std::cout << s << "\n";
}
```

**PS.** Consider a regular expression split algorithm though:

<kbd>**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6aeca25fe604e2ad)**</kbd>

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string line("one;two#three//four five\r\n"
            "six");

    boost::regex re("[^a-zA-Z0-9]");
    boost::sregex_token_iterator i(line.begin(), line.end(), re, -1), j;
    std::vector<std::string> split_(i, j);

    for(auto const& s : split_)
        std::cout << s << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Added the - probably more efficient, and certainly more flexible, Boost Regex approach